# Failed to do failover in 3 node patroni postgres-11 cluster

Tags: postgresql-11, patroni

I have a three node `patroni` `postgres-11` cluster running.The patroni cluster settings are:

```
consul:
  url: <consul URL>

bootstrap:
  initdb:
    encoding: UTF8
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
      use_slots: true
      remove_data_directory_on_diverged_timelines: false
      remove_data_directory_on_rewind_failure: true
      parameters:
        archive_command: /bin/true
        archive_mode: 'on'
        archive_timeout: 1800s
        checkpoint_completion_target: 0.9
        default_statistics_target: 100
        effective_cache_size: 24GB
        effective_io_concurrency: 200
        hot_standby: 'on'
        log_directory: /var/log/postgresql
        log_filename: postgresql-%a.log
        logging_collector: 'on'
        maintenance_work_mem: 2GB
        max_connections: 2000
        max_parallel_maintenance_workers: 4
        max_parallel_workers: 8
        max_parallel_workers_per_gather: 4
        max_replication_slots: 10
        max_wal_senders: 10
        max_wal_size: 8GB
        max_worker_processes: 8
        min_wal_size: 2GB
        random_page_cost: 1.1
        shared_buffers: 8GB
        ssl: 'on'
        ssl_cert_file: /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        ssl_key_file: /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
        track_commit_timestamp: 'on'
        wal_buffers: 16MB
        wal_keep_segments: 64
        wal_level: logical
        wal_log_hints: 'on'
        work_mem: 5242kB

postgresql:
  listen: 0.0.0.0:5432
  connect_address: <IP Address of the node>:5432
  data_dir: /var/lib/postgresql/11/<db name>
  pgpass: /tmp/pgpass0
  authentication:
    superuser:
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
    replication:
      username: replicator
      password: replicator
    rewind:
      username: rewind_user
      password: rewind_password
  pg_hba:
    - local all all peer
    - host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - hostssl all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - host all postgres 0.0.0.0/0 reject
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - hostssl all postgres ::0/0 md5
    - host all postgres ::0/0 reject
    - host all all ::0/0 md5
    - local replication all peer
    - host replication all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
    - hostssl replication replicator 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - hostssl replication replicator ::0/0 md5
    - host replication replicator 0.0.0.0/0 md5
    - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 trust
    - local postgres   postgres   peer
    - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
  create_replica_methods:
    - basebackup
  basebackup:
    max-rate: '250M'

tags:
  nofailover: false
  noloadbalance: false
  clonefrom: false
  nosync: false

restapi:
  connect_address: <IP Address of the node>:8008
  listen: 0.0.0.0:8008
```

When I shutdown the primary, I was hoping the `synchronous standby` would become primary. But instead on both the standby nodes I see the following error:

```
INFO: following a different leader because i am not the healthiest node
```

Not sure why synchronous standby did not become primary.
I am using `Patroni 1.6.1` on `Ubuntu 18.04`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. For some reason the capital letters in the names of my nodes were converted to small letters so patroni failed to find the standby nodes. Like below:

```
{"leader":"Pa-db1","sync_standby":"pa-db2"}
```

The correct name of the node is Pa-db2 and similarly the second standby node name is Pa-db3. I changed all the nodes names to small letters i.e. `pa-db1, pa-db2, pa-db3` and failover worked!